# How to export SQL database without structure using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup

i want to build functionality to export database in system, but i don't want to give structure of database in export at client level.

Is it possible to get export of only data of all tables ?

why need this ?

- a copy of structure of database not want to relieve at end level users.
- in case of loosing data, owner of system can restore database structure and import client's data which they get with this export.
- there is always have structure of database with company.

Comment: Sure, just loop through every table and print the values into a .txt file for your backup. No seriously, why would you do this? How are you going to restore the backup if you remove all structure? Foreign key constraints/ Relations?

Comment: read the each table and data and create the file using loop

Comment: No.  **The point of a *backup* is to save a copy that allows you to reconstruct the original if needed.**  The structure is critical information, and if you omit it, you could never recreate the original.  Thus it is not a backup.  You could do *something* to just extract the data without the structure, but it's not clear why you would want to do this.  Perhaps you could update the question to clarify what you are hoping to accomplish with this.

Comment: What good would that back up be? It's going to take you awhile to restore it.

Comment: @RushilPachchigar : this is not duplicate , as that question mentions that export only Structure while i want to export only Data.

Comment: @dan1111 i just edited my quetion.

Comment: Hi there, it seems to me like you said at title, an *export*, not a backup, but you start text saying _i want to build functionality to backup database in system_ I recommend backup with mysqldump, or do the export like the comments said, looping tables and exporting them in TXT or XML, etc. But don't try to use this export logic to restore your database, because isn't a backup... In other words: do one thing (backup) ~or~ another (export), not half of both.

Comment: Are you trying to export CSVs of specific user's data? The question is unclear to me. If you have the full DB as a text blob you will have a had time getting the data back to the correct tables/columns.

Comment: I still don't think that makes sense.  Any data that is stored in a format sufficient to allow reconstruction of the database would allow the client to infer the data structure, even if you haven't explicitly given it.  You would at least have to store the fields in something like a CSV with no headers, and is it really hard to figure out the table structure for something like this: `1, John, Doe, 123 Fake St, Springfield, IL, 12345, 123-456-7890`

Comment: @FernandoMertins yes, thanks. i made rev of question.

Comment: @dan1111 it is easy to figure out data in that , but they cannot figure out trigger and relations of tables if its only data.